# perl taint mode: Insecure dependency

Tags: perl

> ``` ERROR: Insecure dependency in `` while running with -T switch at ```

I am executing a bash script from perl script.

```
my $date_tmp="31-DEC-2016";
my $new  = `/bin/sh ./compareDate.sh "$date_tmp"`;
```

I will capture output in my variable `$new`. How do I accomplish this while `perl` is running with taint mode on?

Comment: Is that how you are setting `$date_tmp` in your actual program?

Comment: Or why do you need to shell out? There's one or two date modules Perl can use.

Comment: even perl's built-in date and time handling functions are far better than anything available in sh.  see `perldoc -f localtime`

Answer (score 4):

From [perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html):

```
   ...otherwise the only way to bypass the
   tainting mechanism is by referencing subpatterns from a regular
   expression match.  Perl presumes that if you reference a substring
   using $1, $2, etc., that you knew what you were doing when you wrote
   the pattern.
```

So assuming you need to get data from an external script and act on it, you need to validate the data you do get.  I'll go out on a limb and suggest that your `compareDate.sh` is expected to return the number of days between the given date and today.  Similar to:

```
$ /bin/sh ./compareDate.sh "$date_tmp"
42
```

Then it can be cleaned up like this:

```
my $new  = `/bin/sh ./compareDate.sh "$date_tmp"`;    # TAINTED
if ($new =~ /^(\d+)$/) {
  $new = $1;                                          # Not tainted
} else {
  die "Unexpected output from compareDate.sh!\n";
}
```

The code didn't simply untaint the variable (although that is possible by being overly permissive with our checks), it validated that it had what was expected.   If someone had messed with it so that it instead contained:

```
$ /bin/sh ./compareDate.sh "$date_tmp"
42; /bin/rm -rf *;
```

Then the validation would fail.  Only numbers can get through and we don't expect them to give us any trouble.  Obviously more complex output might require more validation.

---

When I wrote the above, I was looking at the code primarily, and there `$date_tmp` is assigned a literal string from the code and must be untainted.  But as jordanm points out, the error message is telling us that the backtick execution is not happening at all.  Rather than the shell's output being the problem, some earlier taint is preventing it from running.

The only variable in the backticks is `$date_tmp`, so a similar validation needs to happen on it between assignment and use in the backticks.

Comment: My suspicion is that the OP is not statically setting date_tmp (as per jordanm's question/comment), and is setting it statically in the question as an example. If date_tmp had any user input, then it would need to be untainted before passing to backticks. I don't think perl cares about the $new assignment itself.

Comment: Good point.  Unfortunately I paid more attention to the code than I did to the error message.